# how to post JSON obj with attribute, to an API url using PHP?

Tags: php, json, post

really stumped at how to approach this - i need to:

> take some json data with an attribute, PHP post to an api/url. 
>   should i have a json file in a folder, then from a file call another URL and pass it the JSON? 
>   then how can i return calculation results via JSON?
>   to learn this, i have an array of numbers, then will perform calculations to return Mean, Median, Mode, and Range.
>   then the working files need to be available to an API.

```
sample json data to post:
{
"numbers": [
5, 6, 8, 7, 5
]
}
```

Sample JSON return response from a single endpoint called "/mmmr" [abbrev for the calculations]:

```
{
  "results": {
  "mean": 6.2,
  "median": 6,
  "mode": 5,
  "range": 3 
  }
}
```

been searching, trying things for hours, not clicking at all. i have a class Calculate that i call and it returns the results for the calculations already, but how to "make it available via API"? please some sample working code, then perhaps i can understand by seeing it.

Comment: `Api Endpoint` -> `does processing` -> `creates array` -> `json_encode() that array` -> `echo that json_encoded array` -> `receive response from api (which would be the json encoded array)` -> `do what needs doing` -> **`PROFIT`**?.

Comment: @darren, i will list my interpretation of your steps, with questions:
>navigate to the page that does the processing [which becomes my api url endpoint]
>in that page create array, json_encode it
>echo the jason_encoded array [simply echo it??]
>*receive response from api* <--how to do that?